# Modrewrite rule messes up variables

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the following example URL:

```
http://example.com/phone/iphone-4-vs-iphone-5/vote/123
```

To:

```
http://example.com/product.php?category=phone&p1=iphone-4&p2=iphone-5&user=123
```

I tried the following ModRewrite rule in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(phone)/(.*)-vs-(.*)/vote/([1-9][0-9]*)$ /product.php?category=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&user=$4 [L]
```

I have this in `product.php` file:

```
<?php
   echo $_GET['category'];
   echo '<br />';
   echo $_GET['p1'];
   echo '<br />';
   echo $_GET['p2'];
   echo '<br />';
   echo $_GET['user'];
 ?>
```

The expected output of PHP:

```
phone
iphone-4
iphone-5
123
```

The actual output I get:

```
phone
iphone-4
iphone-5/vote/123
```

Therefore the rewrite rule has something wrong so that it attaches the `user` variable to the `p2` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule should work but you can replace your rule with this non-greedy quantifier and negated class:

```
RewriteRule ^(phone)/(.+?)-vs-([^/]+)(?:/vote/([1-9][0-9]*))?/?$ product.php?category=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&user=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I think I found the mistake. The last variable `user` is an optional one so I mentioned before this rule another rule without the last variable. This is the rule before `RewriteRule ^(phones)/(.*)-vs-(.*)$ /compare.php?category=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3 [L]`. Should the complete rule with all the variables be mentioned above the one without the last variable?? Thanks!

Comment: Ok that is the problem because `.*` matches everything. btw you don't need 2 separate rules. Just keep a single rule as `RewriteRule ^(phone)/(.+?)-vs-([^/]+)(?:/vote/([1-9][0-9]*))?/?$ product.php?category=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&user=$4 [L,QSA,NC]`